# Jquery window.load function and Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the following jquery code in my page:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

    jQuery('#narrow-by-list dd > ol.filter_list').each(function(){
        var FormHeight = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        if(FormHeight > 70){
            jQuery(this).next('.layer_nav_more').css("display", "inline-block");
            jQuery(this).height(70).css("display", "block");
        }else{
            jQuery(this).height(70).css("display", "block");
        }
    });
    jQuery(".layer_nav_more").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).prev('.filter_list').animate({ height:205 }, 500, function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass("scrollable");
        });
    });

});
```

The page also uses ajax calls to update it's content, so after content is refreshed the jquery code is ignored. I don;t think that posting the full js file which handles ajax will help you. I guess that the following lines should be quite ok for you to understand what's going on:

```
requestUrl = document.location.href
if (requestUrl.indexOf('#') >= 0) {
    var requestUrl = requestUrl.substring(0,requestUrl.indexOf('#'));
}

if (requestUrl.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
    requestUrl = requestUrl.replace('?', '?no_cache=true&');
} else {
    requestUrl = requestUrl + '?no_cache=true';
}

requestUrl = this.replaceToolbarParams(requestUrl);

this.showLoading();
new Ajax.Request(requestUrl, {
    method : 'post',
    parameters  : parameters,
    onSuccess: this.onSuccessSend.bindAsEventListener(this),
    onFailure: this.onFailureSend.bindAsEventListener(this)
});
```

What can I do to fix this?

---

**EDIT:**
I changed the code based on David's recommendations

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

    function adjust_list_height(){
        jQuery('#narrow-by-list dd > ol.filter_list').each(function(){
            var FormHeight = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
            if(FormHeight > 70){
                jQuery(this).next('.layer_nav_more').css("display", "inline-block");
                jQuery(this).height(70).css("display", "block");
            }else{
                jQuery(this).height(70).css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    }

    adjust_list_height();

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.layer_nav_more', function(){
        jQuery(this).prev('.filter_list').animate({ height:205 }, 500, function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass("scrollable");
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: what's the problem / issue?

Comment: @ysrb the problem is that the each() function is no longer working after page content is re-loaded using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so after content is refreshed the jquery code is ignored

No it isn't.  It's not going to be automatically re-invoked, clearly, but why should it be?  The handler you posted is for the window's load event.  Unless you're loading the window again, I wouldn't expect the code to execute again.

It *sounds like* the problem is that you're adding new elements to the page after you've added `click` handlers to existing elements.  Keep in mind that [handlers are attached to *elements*, not to *selectors*](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html).  So if a particular element doesn't exist when you execute this code, it's not going to get a click handler.

The standard approach to this is to defer handling click events to parent elements.  Any common parent element will do, as long as it's not removed/replaced during the life of the page.  `document` is often used for this, but any parent `div` or anything like that would work just as well.  Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.layer_nav_more', function(){
    //...
});
```

What this does is attach the actual click handler to `document` instead of to the matching `.layer_nav_more` elements.  When any element invokes a click, that event will propagate upwards through the parent elements and invoke any click handlers on them.  When it gets to this handler on the `document`, jQuery will filter for the originating element using that second selector.  So this will effectively handle any clicks from `.layer_nav_more` elements.

Any *other* functionality that you need to invoke when the page content changes (functionality besides delegate-able event handlers) would need to be re-invoked when you logically need to do so.  For example, executing `.each()` over a series of elements like you're doing.  There's no way to "defer" that, so you'd want to encapsulate it within a function of its own and simply execute that function whenever you need to re-invoke that logic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Please take a look of the question update. Should I call adjust_list_height() inside onSuccessSend function?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried to add jQuery('.layer_nav_more').css("display", "inline-block"); at the ned of onSuccessSend() function, but it didn't work. I belive tha this is the function that I should add the jquery effects, right?